# How can I chain rotationAnimation?

Tags: java, android, animation

I would like to rotate an ImageView. But I want to rotate from 0 to 45 to -45 and return to 0 to sumarize my objectives.

I try to create 4 `rotationAnimation` and to chain them with `AnimatorSet`.

Here my code :

```
    rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 45, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate.setDuration(1000);
    rotate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotate1 = new RotateAnimation(45, -45, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate1.setDuration(1000);
    rotate1.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotate2 = new RotateAnimation(-45, 45, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate2.setDuration(1000);
    rotate2.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    rotate3 = new RotateAnimation(45, 0, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotate3.setDuration(1000);
    rotate3.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    setAnim= new AnimationSet(true);
    setAnim.addAnimation(rotate);
    setAnim.addAnimation(rotate1);
    setAnim.addAnimation(rotate2);
    setAnim.addAnimation(rotate3);
img.startAnimation(setAnim);
```

For the moment the image go suddendly without rotation to 45° and return to 0°.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AnimationListener`

Example

```
yourFirstAnim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
      doYourNextAnim()
    }
  });
```

or a simpler way, using `AnimatorSet()`

```
AnimatorSet as = new AnimatorSet();
as.playSequentially(yourFirstAnim, 
                    yourSecondAnim,
                    ..,
                    ...);
as.setDuration(YOUR_DURATION);
as.start();
```

**Update**
To avoid callback hell, we can use `StartDelay`

```
imgAvatar1.animate()
        .alpha(1f)
        .setDuration(YOUR_DURATION)
        .start()

    imgAvatar2.animate()
        .alpha(1f)
        .setStartDelay(YOUR_DURATION * 1)
        .setDuration(YOUR_DURATION)
        .start() 

    imgAvatar3.animate()
        .alpha(1f)
        .setStartDelay(YOUR_DURATION * 2)
        .setDuration(YOUR_DURATION)
        .start()
```

Comment: The `setAnimationListener` works for me but the `Animatorset()`  not working for my case. Thanks for the first solution.

Comment: @BartekLipinski you right, bro, so I updated my answer to ignore callback hell

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a chain correctly with your `AnimationSet()`.

The problem is probably with the `fillAfter` param.

Use `setFillAfter(true)` on your `rotate` animations, so the animated parameter is applied after the animation.

Comment: I add `rotate.setFillAfter(true)` for all my `rotationAnimation` but nothing change.